# Is it possible to break Windows 10 password (login screen) without rebooting?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, bitlocker, login-screen

I have Windows 10 installed on my laptop with BitLocker activated, but I like to put it in sleep mode with a login password. If someone steals my laptop in this state, how secure would my data be? Since BitLocker doesn't encrypt the data in sleep mode, the only protection it has is the login password. If the stealer reboot my computer, BitLocker would encrypt it again (let's disregard cold boot attacks here) and everything is ok, but what if the stealer knows it has BitLocker and try to access the data without rebooting the computer. How secure it is with Windows login password?

Comment: How old is your system? On old system one could insert a pc-card (like Firewire) that allows Direct memory Access (DMA) and therefore allows to read/write to the computer  memory and override the login system. I am not sure what counter measure Windows 10 has in that scenario, but I remember that mostly it depends on the security features of CPU+chipset.

Comment: @Robert it's relatively new. A Dell G3 laptop from 2018 with i7 8th gen and DDR4 RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a vulnerability.

According to this [article](https://betanews.com/2020/05/11/thunderspy-security-vulnerability/), there's a tool called Thunderspy which uses modern DMA attack and is able to get your data even if the computer is suspended and encrypted.

> Thunderspy works even if you follow best security practices by locking
> or suspending your computer when leaving briefly, and if your system
> administrator has set up the device with Secure Boot, strong BIOS and
> operating system account passwords, and enabled full disk encryption.
> All the attacker needs is 5 minutes alone with the computer, a
> screwdriver, and some easily portable hardware.

So, yes, that's possible.

Answer (score 3):

> Since BitLocker doesn't encrypt the data in sleep mode, the only protection it has is the login password.

**BitLocker protection absolutely is enabled while a machine is in sleep mode.**  BitLocker is a full disk encryption solution, the only way to access your data, is to provide the password to your username or the BitLocker recovery key.  Windows by default, automatically locks an account, after the number of invalid attempts, defined by the group policy has been reached.

If BitLocker protection has been suspended then it's key is written to the disk.  This could be used in theory in an attack, but since the key exists on the disk that is fully encrypted, it would still require access to the user account to be accessed.

> If the stealer reboot my computer, BitLocker would encrypt it again (let's disregard cold boot attacks here) and everything is ok, but what if the stealer knows it has BitLocker and try to access the data without rebooting the computer.

BitLocker can only be disabled or suspended if a malicious party has access to your user account.  **Outside of Windows the BitLocker recovery is required.**

> How secure it is with Windows login password?

Your files cannot be access without the recovery key and/or access to your user account.  Since the user account is automatically is locked, after several invalid attempts, access to your account is secure.  **Any configuration change will result in the BitLocker recovery key being required to boot the system.**

> If someone steals my laptop in this state, how secure would my data be?

Your files are encrypted.

Comment: My bad. I thought it was not encrypted because BitLocker doesn't require PIN after resuming from sleep mode. Anyways, the central point of the question is the Windows lock screen security. Maybe a DMA attack or something as sophisticated could bypass it?

Comment: I have answered your question.

Comment: You mentioned invalid attempts, but there could be a DMA attack that would bypass the lock screen even with a invalid password.

Comment: @EduardoM - If a malicious party has access to your machine and is able to perform a DMA attack without you preventing that from happening, no amount of security, will prevent their access to your machine.  **However, I still maintain, I have answered your question.**

Comment: Of course. I don't think you have answered my question because you say "if someone is able to perform a DMA attack, they will be able to access your data" . I know it. My question is if there's a known method to perform it or any similar way to achieve it. I know Windows 10 has protections against DMA attacks, it was only a example.

Comment: You asked only two questions within your question.  I have addressed both of those questions.  Your question made no mention of a DMA attack within the body of your question.  I am not going to answer unrealistic questions submitted as a temporary comment.  **I suppose I will just delete this answer since it’s unhelpful.**

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has a TPM that is being used, it might be safe even when asleep.

If the key is in RAM, all bets are off against a moderately well equipped attacker. There is a very real possibility that the thief, if they were specifically after your data, could remove the DIMM, plug it into a memory tester, and read out all of the memory contents and save them to a file for analysis. The chances are that there is a sequence of 32 bytes in the RAM that is the key. Also, I don't think the cache is kept encrypted, so that may well be dumpable directly.

The DIMM pull and dump attack was demonstrated years ago. If I remember correctly, DIMM contents were completely recoverable for quite a few seconds after power loss.

If you have a reason to be paranoid, do a full shutdown and make sure you have a TPM.

Answer (score 0):

> Since BitLocker doesn't encrypt the data in sleep mode, the only protection it has is the login password.

Your data is always encrypted,regardless of the state of the system.

When you're logged on, Windows has access to the recovery key so it can show you the information.

When somebody tries to unlock / login to your computer, then bit locker has nothing to do, it's Windows and your password protecting your pc.

Bitlocker is protecting against access circumventing windows protection (reinstall or remove hard disk)